# how talib is detecting patterns?

Tags: python, ta-lib

```
sample_data = [
    ['1/22/14', 10, 18, 5, 20],
    ['1/23/14', 12, 21, 7, 22],
    ['1/24/14', 14, 24, 9, 24],
    ['1/25/14', 16, 27, 11, 26],
    ['1/26/14', 18, 30, 13, 28],
    ['1/27/14', 20, 33, 15, 30],
    ['1/28/14', 22, 36, 17, 32],
    ['1/29/14', 24, 39, 19, 34],
    ['1/30/14', 26, 41, 21, 38],
    ['1/31/14', 30, 45, 25, 30],
    ['2/03/14', 241.75, 243.15, 240.65, 241.80],
    ['1/31/14', 30, 45, 25, 30],
]

# convert data to columns
sample_data = np.column_stack(sample_data)

# extract the columns we need, making sure to make them 64-bit floats
o = sample_data[1].astype(float)
h = sample_data[2].astype(float)
l = sample_data[3].astype(float)
c = sample_data[4].astype(float)

print(talib.CDLDOJI(o, h, l, c))
```

output is : [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 100]

but if you look at data last and third last data is the same but still, it is not detecting it, I have noticed that it only starts detecting patterns after 10 candles have passed is this right or I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code:

> /* real body is like doji's body when it's shorter than 10% the
>   average of the **10** **previous** candles' high-low range */

And function return 0 or 100 in case candle is detected.
So first 10 values must be 0.

Comment: Can you provide the link to documentation I can't find it?

Comment: Well, it's a commentary in the code. In default candle detection settings: https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_common/ta_global.c#l151  It's accessed via TA_CANDLEAVGPERIOD(BodyDoji); template in CDLDOJI function implementation: https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_CDLDOJI.c#l209   The library is written with pure C language and it often uses C templates, so the code quite hard to navigate.